# how to convert .content().filter method from jquery to vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been using the following code in jquery.

```js
$('p').contents().filter(function() {
  if ($(this).closest('#header , .header, #bottom').length > 0) {
    return false;
  }
  return (this.nodeType === 3 && /\S/.test(this.nodeValue)); //Node.TEXT_NODE
}).each(function(i, tn) {
  // push tn into array
});
```

I want this code to be written in vanilla javascript as I want to completely remove the dependency from jQuery.

I've tried something like this but it doesn't work. I can't find a substitute for JQuery's contents() and then the filter method which can help me achieve the above objective.

```js
var nodelist = document.querySelectorAll('p');
//console.log(nodelist);
Array.from(nodelist).filter(function(node, i) {
  var closest = nodelist[i].closest('#header , .header, #bottom');
  if (closest) {
    return false;
  } else {
    console.log(nodelist[i].nodeType)
    return (nodelist[i].nodeType === 3 && /\S/.test(nodelist[i].nodeValue)); //Node.TEXT_NODE
  }
}).forEach(function(tn, i) {
  console.log(tn)
});
```

Comment: I made you two snippets. Please add relevant HTML and CSS to have two [mcve]s and tell us expected output

Comment: contents: node.querySelectorAll("*") perhaps

Comment: `contents()` returns the child nodes of each `<p>`. You are only looking at the actual `<p>` elements in your attempt